# ordering mysql table using an equation with $_GET variables

Tags: php, mysql

Here is what i am trying to do

```
{
{
    $sql="SELECT ISO_id,gdp,population,country_name,gold,silver,bronze,total FROM Country ORDER BY (46034/($_GET["x"]*bronze)+($_GET["y]*silver]+(z*gold)*(gdp/population))"; // chosen to order my html table with the number the medals each country won at the olympics
    }
    }
```

however i do not know how to include the $_GET inside the statements

Comment: There is an SQL injection possible with your query. Use [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) instead.

Comment: You should use a prepared statement for this, and bind the $_GET values.

Comment: you have to put a column name after ORDER BY statement, i don't know wha you try to do here

Answer (score 0):

To use a $_GET parameter in your current statement, use:

```
$sql="
    SELECT ISO_id,gdp,population,country_name,gold,silver,bronze,total 
    FROM Country
    ORDER BY (46034/(" . $_GET["x"] . "*bronze)+(" . $_GET["y"] . "*silver]+(z*gold)*(gdp/population))";
```

However, please be aware that this leaves you open to SQL Injection attacks, so you should consider filtering your input before using it in such a query. For details, see [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Also, please note that there appears to be an error in your `ORDER BY` clause as stated by Nagasaki in the comments. You should order on a column name.

Comment: thats what im trying to do im trying to order the table by this equation

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="SELECT 
    ISO_id,
    gdp,
    population,
    country_name,
    gold,
    silver,
    bronze,
    total,
    (46034/(" . $_GET["x"] . "*bronze)+(" . $_GET["y"] . "*silver]+(z*gold)*(gdp/population)) as number_medals
FROM Country
ORDER BY number_medals";
```

Be careful of sql injection....

Answer (score 0):

its a good idea to first make the get variable into a separate variable then from there clean it up because putting get variables straight into an sql statement leaves you open to sql injection.

Say the url looks like this. http://www.mysite.com?ID=4
to get at the id you would go 
$_GET[ID] or to be safe $id = $_GET[ID] and from here do some work to clean any bad data from the id.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php
this will help you out a bit but still its never 100% save.

I remember back when i was trying to figure this out and i didnt want to look at alternatives i just wanted to make it work but a word of advice would be to use PDO prepared statements. They are a little tricky to understand at first but this guide is pretty good and will explain how to do it quite easily. PDO keeps you safe from sql injection.

[PDO Prepared Statement Tutorial](http://nerdburglars.net/tutorial.php?ID=4)

Answer (score -1):

just add Braces

{ { $sql="SELECT ISO_id,gdp,population,country_name,gold,silver,bronze,total FROM Country ORDER BY (46034/({$_GET["x"]}*bronze)+({$_GET["y]}*silver]+(z*gold)*(gdp/population))"; // chosen to order my html table with the number the medals each country won at the olympics } }

Comment: There is still SQL injection possible with this answer. Don't do this!

Comment: that makes absolutely no sense ?

Comment: i know there is SQL injection possible but i am trying to do this for practicing coding i want to know how to include $_GET statements and numbers in the mysql statement